# SQL Like statement not return a wildcard output asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

i have these sql statement to output job field based on user input.

```
    SELECT jf.name, j.jname, c.cname, cj.url
    FROM company_has_job cj
        INNER JOIN job j ON j.id = cj.job_id
        INNER JOIN company c ON c.id = cj.company_id
        INNER JOIN jobfield_has_job jhj ON jhj.job_id = j.id
        INNER JOIN jobfield jf ON jf.id = jhj.jobfield_id
    WHERE jf.name LIKE '%' + @InputJob + '%'
```

for example when user input query "**Programmer**", the system will output all programmer job defined in the database.but the system does not show any result if i enter "**Program**" in the search box. This is my control parameter:

```
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox4" Name="InputExpertise" 
        PropertyName="Text"/>
</SelectParameters>
```

can you tell me where i did wrong? your help is much appreciated.

Comment: What's the Type of @InputJob - is is Char, VarChar, nVarChar?

Comment: Ah. If it was `char` it might have been a whitespace issue but if not then I don't have an answer, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if this is just a typo, but shouldn't it be

```
WHERE jf.name LIKE '''%' + @InputJob + '%'''
```

Notice that I made it so that the code will end up as `LIKE '%Program%'`, whereas it looks like it will end up as `LIKE %Program%` currently.

Comment: I checked but there is no typo in the code.thanks anyway for your advise

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment yet, but perhaps this will answer the question, do any of the columns that you join on allow NULLs?  The inner join will not return results that include a null.

consider this query:

```
select wb.employee,wb.Dept from web_user wb
inner join Employee e on wb.Dept = e.Department
where wb.employee like '%Ted%'
```

No results

but this:

```
select wb.employee,wb.Dept from web_user wb
left join Employee e on wb.Dept = e.Department
where wb.employee like '%Ted%'
```

Returns:
Ted NULL

Also it my be helpful to debug, set a breakpoint on the actual call to the database to get the SQL statement it is using and then paste that into a query editor.  I've done this many times when a query does not behave.  Once you know what the program is using for the SQL statement that may also help you find the issue.